# Why hide the relationship from Tom?

Tags: plot-explanation, goliath

During season 2 of Goliath, Gabriel hides his "familial" relationship to Marisol from Tom and in one episode, Gabriel explicitly tells Tom that he doesn't know her and that Tom is the one who knows Marisol and has a relationship with her. Later we learn that Gabriel and Marisol are brother/sister and when Billy tells this to Tom, Tom gets upset about it.

Why? What was the point of hiding the relationship from Tom?